# Add ssh pass phrase after setup?

Tags: ssh, debian, debian-jessie, passphrase

Can an ssh pass phrase added after ssh is already setup? I'm using Debian 8 stable Jessie 8.7. And how can you save it in Debian like in a keyring so you do not have to enter it everytime? Thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to add a pass phrase to an existing ssh key that is not secured with a password?

You can change the pass phrase with `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/private-key-file
```

Answer (score 2):

SSH uses your normal user password, so it can be changed with the `passwd` command on the machine you're connecting to.

By default, Debian has public/private key authentication enabled, so you can use RSA keys instead of a passphrase, if you put your public key on the system you're connecting to. First, you need to create a key on your local machine:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then, put it on the remote server. Type this command on your local machine:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remotehost "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Then you will no longer need a password to log in.

EDIT: @EEAA brings up a good point: `ed25519` is a much better cryptographic system nowadays than `RSA`, and it might be a good idea to start switching. You can create an `ed25519` public/private key pair and copy it to your remote system like so:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | ssh user@remotehost "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

There's an interesting read regarding ed25519 vs RSA [over in the StackExchange IS community](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90077/ssh-key-ed25519-vs-rsa)

Comment: These days we should be recommending usage of ed25519 keys over rsa.

Comment: @EEAA Good point. Answer updated.